# how to unpack a list while returning it?

Tags: python

```
def function(inputlist, outputlist,**kwargs):
    def f(*inputlist, **kwargs):
        return outputlist
    return f
```

will return a list, But I want the return value to be seperate values.

Comment: Can you show an example of what is happening currently, and what is the desired behavior ?

Comment: What's the difference between returning a list or returning multiple values?

Comment: What do you would like to ask exactly?! Currently, the `function` will return another function which is `f`, and the function `f` take the `inputlist` and `**kwargs` as input as it will always return the `outputlist`. For instance, you use function like this: `a = function([1,2,'abc'], [],v1=10, v2=20)`, then `a` will be `<function __main__.f>`. And `a()` is actually `f()`, and the returned value will be `[]`

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  I already got a solution.!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `n` value in `outputlist`. Then instead of

```
return outputlist
```

you'd like to

```
return outputlist[0], outputlist[1], ..., outputlist[n]
```

Obviously

```
return *outputlist
```

does not work and raises a `SyntaxError`.

Considering

```
return v1, v2, v3
```

is the same as

```
return (v1, v2, v3)
```

you could just

```
return tuple(outputlist)
```

to achieve what you want.

But in the end it will behave almost the same like returning the list itself in regard to unpacking.

Comment: Thanks! but in this case, the return value is a tuple not single value.

Comment: I finally end up using the following. def function(inputlist, outputlist,**kwargs):
    def f(*inputlist, **kwargs):
        if len(outputlist) == 1:
            return outputlist[0]
        else:
            return outputlist
    return f